# This very simple guess game does not work

Tags: java

**I try to make a very simple guess game and i wanted to add an exciting addition by doing an analysis of the guesswork from the user using switch function but I was surprised that it did not run that analysis**

```
public static void main (String args[]){

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ROOT);

int num = 8 , guess;
boolean positiveguess = true;
while (positiveguess) {
System.out.println("Enter your guess = ");
guess = reader.nextInt();
if (guess != num)
    switch(guess)
    {
        case '1':
            if (num-5 < guess && num + 5 >guess)
                System.out.println("Your guess is almost close! \nTry again ");
       break;
        case '2':
            if (num-10 < guess && num + 10 >guess)
                System.out.println("You need to guess again ");
        break;    
    }              
else
    positiveguess = false;
    
}
System.out.println("Great !");
```

Comment: You are branching on character values  , not int values, i.e replace `case '1'` with `case 1` and so on ..

Comment: I'm confused about your usage of `num` in your checks here... are you trying to see if the `guess` is within a certain range of that `num`? You could achieve this more easily by doing `int accuracy = Math.abs(num - guess);` followed by checks like `if(accuracy < 5){ //close accuracy message } else if (accuracy < 10) { //not so accurate message } else { //not accurate at all message }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch is based on the user input and not the difference between given and exepcted value. First I suggest you to keep it simple with `if/else` structure like

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ROOT);

        int num = 8, guess;
        boolean positiveguess = true;
        while (positiveguess) {
            System.out.println("Enter your guess = ");
            guess = reader.nextInt();
            if (guess != num) {
                if (num - 5 < guess && num + 5 > guess) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is almost close! \nTry again ");
                } else if (num - 10 < guess && num + 10 > guess) {
                    System.out.println("You need to guess again ");
                }
            } else {
                positiveguess = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Great !");
    }
}
```

Then I suggest you to remove your `positiveguess` and do a `while` loop with your condition inside. And use `Math.abs()` to get the difference between the guess and the expected value.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ROOT);

        int num = 8;
        int guess = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        while (guess != num) {
            System.out.println("Enter your guess = ");
            guess = reader.nextInt();

            int diff = Math.abs(num - guess);
            if (diff != 0) {
                if (diff < 5) {
                    System.out.println("Your guess is almost close! \nTry again ");
                } else if (diff < 10) {
                    System.out.println("You need to guess again ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You're way too far bro");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Great !");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `switch` wrongly here. It seems you are looking for something like this:

```
switch (guess) {
    // first case
    case (num-5 < guess && num + 5 >guess):
        System.out.println("Your guess is almost close! \nTry again ");
    // second case
    case (num-10 < guess && num + 10 >guess):
        System.out.println("You need to guess again ");
}
```

But this is **not valid syntax**. In Java, a `switch/case` can only compare elements to other elements of the same type (or, in newer version, *multiple* elements, or a class), not perform complex conditional checks like `if` can.
Probably you then tried to "fix" it by combining `case '1'` and the `if` statements, but while legal, `case '1'` will only be the case if `guess` is `'1'` (i.e. 49), and *only then* will continue to check the `if` condition.

Instead, just drop the `switch/case` and use your `if` statements directly (don't forget the `else`):

```
if (num-5 < guess && num+5 > guess) {
    System.out.println("Your guess is almost close! \nTry again ");
} else if (num-10 < guess && num+10 > guess) {
    System.out.println("You need to guess again ");
}
```

Also, you could make those checks more readable by changing the order to `(num-5 < guess && guess < num+5)` or using `Math.abs` to find the absolute difference and use that in the condition.